# Semantic UI - UI Search DropDown not showing up

Tags: frontend, semantic-ui

Ref: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

When i try to build a searchable select dropdown, the DropDown does not even show up on the page.

This is easily reproducible.

Please refer to the fiddle at `http://jsfiddle.net/4woemsjt/6/`

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
  <option value="">State</option>
</select>
```

Appreciate if someone could help me get past this error. Am i missing some script inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling .dropdown() over the select selector in the document ready function.